# Как объявить переменную через eval / new Function?

Tags: javascript, eval

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что переменные, объявленные в eval, не видны при следующем вызове eval. Что можно придумать? Пытаюсь сделать js REPL на js.

```js
// Вот так работает - 
console.log(eval(`
  let t = 1;
  ++t;
`)); // > 2


// А вот так уже нет -
eval('let t = 1;');
try{
    eval('++t;'); // > t is not defined!
}catch(e){console.error(e)}
```

Comment: вопрос в окружении. замени let на var и все заработает

Comment: @Grundy Я и так знаю что с var работает) Что с let делать? REPL без let - это было бы странно. Можно поставить вопрос более широко - как заставить два отдельных вызова eval выполнится в одном скопе? Проблемы с этим ведь повылазят не только с let

Comment: В текущем коде - никак, так как при вызове создается [Lexical Environment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-lexical-environments) и объявление `let` ограничено именно им, а не функцией. Поэтому стоит изменить подход к твоей реализации repl

Comment: @Grundy На какой? Я в тупике, поэтому вопрос и задал

Comment: например отказаться от использования нативного eval

Comment: Для нормального repl надо в любом случае парсить строки, чтобы можно было многострочные функции объявлять. Вот при этом парсинге  и надо заменить let в блоках верхнего уровня на var.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, но он ж тогда будет работать как var, а не как let :)

Comment: @Grundy и в чем же отличие в контексте repl?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, ну как, при следующем же `let a` repl Должен кинуть ошибку, ведь переопределить переменную нельзя, а если не должен, и все ограничено одним текстовым куском, то и так все отлично работает, так как при отправке будет всего один eval

Answer (score 1):

```js
eval('let a = 1;');
eval('var b = 1;');

console.log(typeof a);
console.log(typeof b);

{let c = 1;}
let d = 1;

console.log(typeof c);
console.log(typeof d);

let e = {};
eval('e.a = 1;');
console.log(e);
```

Comment: где пояснения-то почему это именно так работает? :-)